# How to remove Windows after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Vista 64 bit machine and I thought it was going to uninstall Vista but it didn't, now I have both systems.  How do I get rid of Vista?

Answer (score 3):

just install OS-Uninstaller

to install it follow this:

- open a new Terminal and write this commands:
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
- press <kbd>enter</kbd> then type: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller`
- launch OS-Uninstaller (**System** -> **Administration** -> **OS-Uninstaller** menu if you use Gnome, or via the dash if you use Unity), then choose the OS you want to remove and click "OK"

more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller